# Is there a way (or working plugin) that will select all Slices and export them from Sketch?

Tags: export, slices, sketch-app

So I've been working on mobile projects lately and I'm using InVision and Hype3. An issue I keep running into is having to export updated Assets (tab bar, action bar, icons, etc) and there is no way that I've found (which works) to select all Slices and export them.

I can do this manually though in many cases I'm nesting slices so that I can export group content only without a background (shadows/material). Obviously time consuming, and I'm curious if anyone has any solutions?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could write the slicing info down and split the image with ImageMagick

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you're using InVision, I suggest that you take a look at Invision Sync ([download link](http://www.invisionapp.com/app/InVisionSync.zip)).

It automatically exports **every Artboard** and **every slice** of your .sketch document and also uploads them to your InVision project.

You can try this approach to see if it fits your needs. You can also find the long version of what I said above in the [official blog post](http://blog.invisionapp.com/sketch-meet-rapid-hi-fi-prototyping/) announcing this feature.

PS. I'm not affiliated to InVision.

Comment: Hmm... I've been using Sync. Maybe it's a setting. Honestly I forget what I was doing when I asked this question, so which project I was experiencing this with is a mystery to me.